# Tkinter, abrir apenas interface gráfica

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá, quando executo um programa que criei utilizando a biblioteca Tkinter em Python, ele abre juntamente com a interface gráfica o console. Sabem como faço para apenas abrir a interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta salvar seu arquivo com a extensão ".pyw" em vez de ".py". (isso é só no Windows - nos outros sistemas um programa Python executado pela interface gráfica não abre um terminal automaticamente)

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado!!!